# Duplicate expires headers on JS causing caching issues

Tags: google-chrome, caching, header, duplicates, expires-header

We are seeing a problem where we have deployed updated JS to web-server. In preparation for this change, caching behavior was supposed to be changed from 8 days to 8 hours, but it seems something has gone wrong.

Instead, when we inspect the JS within chrome developer console, we see two expires headers, one for +8 days, the other for +8 hours.

Furthermore, users are not receiving the updated JS, HOWEVER, their 'expires' headers appear to be updating every day.

i.e. User A will have an expires of Sept 29th today, and the old JS file. Tomorrow if I check with them, the expiry will be Sept 30th, but they will still have the old JS file.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is this behavior definitely an artifact of the double expires headers, and if so can you explain what is happening?

Sorry re. the vagueness. I'm not very technical and am to some extent thrown in the deep-end on this one.